# Why can't the partition leader election logic in Kafka cluster sit in Zookeeper rather than controller broker doing it?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, broker

Quoting this answer -

> kafka uses zookeeper for a few things:
>
> cluster membership - the live brokers of a cluster are those who have
> ephemeral ZK nodes leader election - election of the kafka broker that
> acts as a controller state storage - some (mostly the older) state is
> stored in ZK - the configuration for topics, for example. some state
> that used to be in ZK has been migrated to special topics (consumer
> offsets) and some newer functionality was written to store state
> entirely in kafka (transaction logs, for example). the general trend
> is to stop using state in ZK and instead self-host it (although older
> parts of the code have never been migrated out).
>
> as for why not use ZK for partition leader election - one reason is
> there is logic involved. when electing a cluster leader broker there's
> no preference - any broker will do. this fits well with how ZK-based
> leader-election works (1st memeber to create and own an ephemeral
> znode wins).
>
> when choosing a partition leader, however, you need a little bit more
> logic. for example - you'd like to elect the leader with the "highest
> watermark" (with the most up to date data, remember replication is
> generally async). there's also logic around unclean leader election.
> ZK alone cannot do that, hence it is done by the controller.

Can anyone explain the last 2 paragraphs more?

I tried searching on net, but nothing concrete found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kafka doesn't require Zookeeper anymore, and will remove its dependency in the next major release.

After Kafka 0.9, several Zookeeper-like functions were moved to the broker.

But otherwise, Zookeeper doesn't track topic offsets (i.e. watermarks). That's all the last paragraph is saying